# Javascript HTML OnSubmitForm and PHP Post

Tags: javascript, php, post

I am sending the user to different pages based on their selection from the drop down menu. This is working fine, but the problem is the Value from the Selection Menu is not making it to my PHP Variable via POST.

The code takes me to the correct page and when I use GET instead of POSTost on the PHP Page it works, but it also changes my url from
page-4.php to page-4?myselectednum=4& all the other html form values that I am bringing over are also added to the url

Javascript function

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function goto()
{
    var num = document.getElementById("selectednum").value;
    if (num <= 12 && num > 8) {
        mynum = 12;
    } 
    else if (num <= 8 && num > 4) {
        mynum = 8;
    } 
    else {
        mynum = 4;
    }

    document.my_form.action = 'page-' + mynum + '.php';
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML form. I have other data in the form, but it really is irrelevant to the question.

```
<form name="my_form" onsubmit="return goto(); method="post">    
    <h2>Please Select a Number</h2>
    <select id="selectednum" name="selectednum">
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select> 

</div>
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="goto()" />
</form>
```

Then here is the PHP Variable POST assignment

```
 $myselectednum =($_POST[selectednum]);
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work with _POST instead of _GET on the PHP Page.
Thanks

Comment: maybe you should just add double-quotes like this:
$myselectednum =($_POST["selectednum"]);

Comment: you didn't close the quote on the `onsubmit` attribute in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: I think @ienaxxx is right. Anyway, you can also write: print_r($_POST) to see the real stuff you are getting from the POST request.

Comment: You have a `</div>` without a matching `<div>`

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($_POST)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target your post variable with double quotes:

change:

```
$myselectednum =($_POST[selectednum]);
```

to:

```
$myselectednum =($_POST["selectednum"]);
```

Comment: If PHP sees a name without `$` and it's not a declared constant, it treats it as a string literal. If you have warnings enabled, it prints a warning saying it's doing this. So this isn't the problem.

Comment: You seem to be pretty sure that this is not the problem, yet you are telling me that "if you have warnings enabled" you will see the error. Seems to me that the OP has all error reporting off.

Comment: He might just have warnings turned off, not all errors. But either way, this won't cause the assignment to fail.

Comment: It will. Php will look for a constant named selectednum and never find it.

Comment: Right, it won't find it, so it will treat it as a quoted string. Try it, you'll see.

Comment: I added the double quotes and also closed the onsubmit quote and everything is working now. Thanks for the responses!